# I am using 2 tableviews in single screen, one is plane and second one is custom cell. Only one is working

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

```
NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellID";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (tableView==self.monthTableVW)
{
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[self.monthArr  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.backgroundColor=[ UIColor colorWithRed:224.0f/255.0f green:188.0f/255.0f blue:113.0f/255.0f alpha:0.5f];
}
if (tableView==self.attendanceTBVW)
{
    customeCell *cell1=[[customeCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell1=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        NSArray *cellArr=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"customeCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell=[cellArr objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell1.dateLbl.text=[self.monthArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
return cell;
}
```

I need one table view to use as drop down menu and the second one is to display the data i.e attendanceTBVW which is customCell.

Answer (score 1):

First **set different cell identifier for different table view cell in the storyboard identity inspector**. Then

```
 #import CustomTableViewCell.h
```

Then drag the dateLbl IBoutlet property in this class. Then cast the custom cell in this type.

```
NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellID1";
NSString *customCell = @"cellID2";

UITableViewCell *cell;

if (tableView==self.monthTableVW)
{

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        //cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[self.monthArr  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.backgroundColor=[ UIColor colorWithRed:224.0f/255.0f green:188.0f/255.0f blue:113.0f/255.0f alpha:0.5f];
}
if (tableView==self.attendanceTBVW)
{

    //customeCell *cell1=[[customeCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    //cell1=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        (CustomTableViewCell *)cell = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:customCell];
        NSArray *cellArr=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"customeCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell=[cellArr objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.dateLbl.text=[self.monthArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    }

    //cell1.dateLbl.text=[self.monthArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  }
    return cell;
}
```

Try it. Hope it will work.

Comment: its showing error like "property dateLbl not found on object of type UItableviewCell"

Comment: where did you put the dateLbl property?

Answer (score 0):

From your code it looks you are only returning cell for the drop down menu. You are not returning the cell1 for the attendanceTBVW. Please return individual cells for both table views. Hope it helps.

Comment: we have to return only one expression at the end, i tried a common expression for both but its going exception error

Answer (score 0):

Can you make it like create different cell for different tableview and return its cell individual.

Because both table are different so you have to return different cell for both.

Do this changes in your code.

```
if (tableView==self.monthTableVW) {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellID";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[self.monthArr  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.backgroundColor=[ UIColor colorWithRed:224.0f/255.0f green:188.0f/255.0f blue:113.0f/255.0f alpha:0.5f];
    return cell;
}
if (tableView==self.attendanceTBVW) {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"customeCell";
    customeCell *cell1=[[customeCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell1=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(cell==nil) {
        NSArray *cellArr=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:cellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
        cell=[cellArr objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    cell1.dateLbl.text=[self.monthArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make this changes check it out

```
if (tableView==self.monthTableVW) {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellID";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[self.monthArr  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.backgroundColor=[ UIColor colorWithRed:224.0f/255.0f green:188.0f/255.0f blue:113.0f/255.0f alpha:0.5f];
    return cell;
}
if (tableView==self.attendanceTBVW) {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"customeCell";
    customeCell *cell1=[[customeCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell1=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(cell==nil) {
        NSArray *cellArr=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:cellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
        cell=[cellArr objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    cell1.dateLbl.text=[self.monthArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: with some litle changes it worked for me, kudos..thank u!

Answer (score 0):

```
 UITableViewCell * raj=[[UITableViewCell alloc]init];



if (tableView==self.monthTableVW)
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellID";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[self.monthArr  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.backgroundColor=[ UIColor colorWithRed:224.0f/255.0f green:188.0f/255.0f blue:113.0f/255.0f alpha:0.5f];
    raj= cell;
}
if (tableView==self.attendanceTBVW)
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"customeCell";
    customeCell *cell1=[[customeCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell1=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(cell1==nil) {
        NSArray *cellArr=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:cellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
        cell1=[cellArr objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    cell1.dateLbl.text=[self.monthArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  raj= cell1;
}

return raj;
```

> This one worked for me ..thanks alot